# Set source file properties called with incorrect number of arguments

Tags: smart-contract, eosio.cdt, eosio2.1

When attempting to compile a new contract, I am getting this error. I'm using eosio version 2.1 for this.

```
CMake Error at /home/michael/eosio.cdt/build/lib/cmake/eosio.cdt/EosioCDTMacros.cmake:18 (set_source_files_properties):
  set_source_files_properties called with incorrect number of arguments.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:12 (target_ricardian_directory)
```

Has anyone seen this before?

Here is the content for the CMakeLists.txt file:

```
project(equity)
  
set(EOSIO_WASM_OLD_BEHAVIOR "Off")
find_package(eosio.cdt)

add_contract( equity equity equity.cpp )
target_include_directories( equity PUBLIC ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../include )
target_ricardian_directory( equity ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../ricardian )

add_contract( equity equity_local equity.cpp )
target_include_directories( equity_local PUBLIC ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../include )
target_ricardian_directory( equity_local ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../ricardian )
target_compile_definitions( equity_local PUBLIC LOCAL )
```

Comment: Elaborate your issue further. Contract compilation has nothing to do with eosio. It is affected by eosio.cdt. As error message says, you need to check whether you use CDT macros correctly. How do you add target? Did you call like `add_contract(CONTRACT_NAME TARGET SOURCES)`? Usually it has a similar form to `add_contract(eosio.token eosio.token eosio.token.cpp)`.

Comment: @conr2d I'm using the standard CMakelists that you get when you use eosio-init

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you use eosio.cdt v1.8.0-rc1.

```
macro (target_ricardian_directory TARGET DIR)
  target_compile_options( ${TARGET} PUBLIC -R${DIR} )
  file(GLOB contracts ${DIR}/*.contracts.md ${DIR}/*.clauses.md)
  get_target_property(contract_sources ${TARGET} SOURCES)
  if(contracts)
    set_source_files_properties(${contract_sources} PROPERTIES OBJECT_DEPENDS ${contracts})
  endif()
endmacro()
```

`set_source_files_properties` will be called arguments with `${contract_sources}` and `${contracts}`. We can know that `${contracts}` is not empty, because your error message says `set_source_files_properties` is called.

I suspect the case of empty `${contract_sources}`. `${contract_sources}` is set by `get_target_property(contract_sources ${TARGET} SOURCES)`, so you can check your `add_contract()` macro first. (contract target is usually set by `add_contract` macro) The name of contract should be repeated two times and have following source files like `add_contract(hello hello hello.cpp)`.

Comment: I've added the src/CMakelists.txt file to the question. I believe the add_contract() macro is correct.

Comment: The problem is caused by the target_ricardian_directory line - commenting out these lines caused the problem to go away. I'm not sure why this is the case though, but my code now compiles so I can deal with this problem later.

Answer (score 2):

When both `xx.contracts.md` and `xx.clauses.md` are present, `${contracts}` is a ;-list, which must be quoted. This edited macro defn works for me without complaint in v1.8.1 (using CMake 3.10.2 on Ubuntu 18.04)

```
   macro (target_ricardian_directory TARGET DIR)
      target_compile_options( ${TARGET} PUBLIC -R${DIR} )
      file(GLOB contracts ${DIR}/*.contracts.md ${DIR}/*.clauses.md)
      get_target_property(contract_sources ${TARGET} SOURCES)
      if(contracts)
         set_source_files_properties(${contract_sources} PROPERTIES OBJECT_DEPENDS "${contracts}")
      endif()
   endmacro()
```

Comment: This worked for me, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The solution above was adopted at https://github.com/EOSIO/eosio.cdt/pull/1220